# jQuery qTip in IE9 - Sliding in animation

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, qtip

I'm using the qTip plugin for tooltips. In IE9, the qTip "slides" in when it appears. Sometimes it slides in from the top of the screen, sometimes from the left, seemingly randomly. Everything else works fine, just like it does in other browsers -- the qTip displays with the correct styles, and disappears normally when I leave the element.

I'm stripped it down to all defaults, so my code is now

```
    $('.myclass').qtip({});
```

What is causing IE9 to make the tool tips slide in like that? Is there a way to stop it? In every other browser I've tried, the tool tip just appears. The IE9 animation is not terrible, but kind of distracting.

Is anyone else using qTip in IE9? Are you seeing this behavior?

Edit: the sliding behavior is predictable (not random, as stated above). The first time you trigger a qTip, it will slide in from the upper left-hand corner. The second and subsequent times you trigger that particular qTip, it will slide in horizontally from the left-hand side.

Comment: Can I get a jsfiddle? what what!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the first version of qtip you can take a look at this [forum](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-how-to-disable-the-fly-by-animation-on-1-0) post for a solution. It looks like you will need to modify the plugin in order to fix the issue.  If that doesn't work you can also try the solution in this [post](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-tooltip-slides-from-bottom-to-top-on-the-first-show?highlight=slides).

Answer (score 1):

Did you set its position?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Only create tooltips when document is ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
   // Use the each() method to gain access to each of the elements attributes
   $('#content img').each(function()
   {
      $(this).qtip(
      {
         content: '<a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>', // Give it some content
         position: 'topRight', // Set its position
         hide: {
            fixed: true // Make it fixed so it can be hovered over
         },
         style: {
            padding: '5px 15px', // Give it some extra padding
            name: 'dark' // And style it with the preset dark theme
         }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/fixed

Comment: Yep, I had the position set (before stripping out everything for the question).

Answer (score 1):

This removes or sets the sliding behavior:

```
    $('.tip').qtip({
        position: {
            effect: false
        }
    });
```